# How do you adjust hues in AS3 like a real color wheel?

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, gsap, hue, color-wheel

I want to adjust the hue of an art asset from one bright color to another one, keeping the monochromatic features intact. I will be starting with either a RGBYTP (red, green, blue, yellow, teal, or purple) color; then through hue adjustments, I will be able to make it look like each one of the other RGBYTP colored images.

For example, take any one of these colored eyeballs, and through AS3 hue adjustment, be able to make any of those *other* colored eyeballs. A common technique in web/game design.

[image: eyeballs]
<sub>(source: [quadradius.com](http://quadradius.com/stuff/RandomImagesForLinking/hue-adjusted-eyeballs.jpg))</sub>

I often use GreenSock Animation Platform (TweenLite/TweenMax), but both core AS code and the TweenLite engine don't seem to handle hue as I expect. I want to adjust the hue color wheel by an increment of 60 degrees, which should adjust through all 6 secondary colors nicely, and get a full bodied color result from it. But what I actually get is horrendous. In fact, adjusting the hue of an RGBYTP color returns very weird results; earth tones, pastels, even shades of gray.

[image: bad-hues]
<sub>(source: [quadradius.com](http://quadradius.com/stuff/RandomImagesForLinking/6-colors-all-hue-adjusted.jpg))</sub>

Here is the code I use to generate all those circles with.

```
    for (var j:int = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var baseColor:uint;
            if (j == 0) baseColor = 0xFF0000;
            if (j == 1) baseColor = 0x00FF00;
            if (j == 2) baseColor = 0x0000FF;
            if (j == 3) baseColor = 0xFFFF00;
            if (j == 4) baseColor = 0xFF00FF;
            if (j == 5) baseColor = 0x00FFFF;
            sprite.graphics.beginFill(baseColor);
            sprite.graphics.drawEllipse(40 * i + 10, 300 + (60 * j) + 10, 40, 40);// positioning
            addChild(sprite);
            TweenMax.to(sprite, .5, {colorMatrixFilter:{hue:i * 60 }} );
        }
    }
```

Why do AS3 or TweenLite/Max not handle hues like Photoshop or an artists color wheel? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Flash only supports RGB and ARGB colour formats. You'll need to cycle thru hues and convert each one to RGB format before applying it - googling should provide some algorithms for converting

Comment: I'm already using what many consider to be a great package of algorithms; the GreenSock platform. It is used for tweening, transformations, timers, and color manipulation; and includes a "hue" function. But even their arguably respected hue function seems to return lacking results. The results of the algorithm are in the image with the circles I included. For example, if you start with purple, you can never produce yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the GreenSock platform is using Flash's own [fl.motion.AdjustColor](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/motion/AdjustColor.html), which doesn't perform a particularly great transformation between RGB and HSV, as you've discovered. You have to take into account the perceptual brightness of different colours in order for it to look right, so it's somewhat subjective.

[This page](http://beesbuzz.biz/code/hsv_color_transforms.php) has a good explanation and some sample code with scaling values for a much more natural looking hue shift. You can use that to generate a matrix for a [flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/ColorMatrixFilter.html), then you'll probably have to write a function which takes the current tween time and run it `onUpdate` to use that with TweenMax.

Comment: Thanks, I read up on how colors are perceived with different intensities. It turns out that with the built in Flash and Greensock hue code, there is simply no way to generate certain colors (depending on what color you start with). i.e. Purple will never become yellow. I had a conversation about it over on their forums, and went into more detail at the time because they had a better grasp on it. http://forums.greensock.com/topic/7052-hue-values-around-the-color-wheel-not-saturated-as-expected/
I ended up with similar outcome, using the matrix, and bypassing Adobe's hue code.

Comment: That page's step 2 seems to be exactly what I could have used. And it would be more flexible than my solution over on the greensock forums. If I get a chance, I will revisit my old code and use their U = cos(H*π/180)
W = sin(H*π/180) examples.  Great stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Two colors don't go straight to black on the Real Color Wheel. Yellow goes to brown first and cyan goes to blue first. The brown is reds darkest color before black. Cyan goes to blues darkest color before black. I don't know any java but I sure would like a java wheel like this one. http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/

The yellow eye is using the RGB gradation to dark and that's why it looks greenish, the same for the cyan colored eye. I have the coded gradations in a table I made on this website.
http://www.realcolorwheel.com/colorwheel.htm
You can get the color codes on the source page.

Don, RCW

Comment: Nice color wheel and it looks like you know your color rules! But not sure if that answers it. The top image made in photoshop is just an example of what I want. When using the built in _Hue_ function in the Tweenlite package, I don't get those results at all (_circles_ image). For example, if I start with red, the hue function produces a brown? Purple will never get you anything close to yellow! One of blue's go to near black? It's like the hue algorithm is more suited to "pick another pretty color", rather than a _hue_ adjusted output. Looking more for an AS3 algorithm answer, but thank you